# MS SQL How to Query Amount Based on Oldest Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm joining two tables, tblAccount and tblInvoice. TblAccount has multiple invoices related to each account. I'm trying to query the TotalSavings amount based on the oldest InvoiceDate and if there are two amount values on the same date then I need to sum of those two amounts. I thought I was doing this correct but the below code doesn't give me the desired output.

```
SELECT TA.AccountID,
MIN(TI.InvoiceDate) AS InvoiceDate,
TI.TotalSavings
FROM tblAccount AS TA
LEFT JOIN tblInvoice AS TI
ON TA.AccountID=TI.AccountID
WHERE TI.TotalSavings>0
AND
TI.InvoiceDate IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY TA.AccountID, TI.TotalSavings
ORDER BY TA.AccountID
```

When i join two tables, i have the below results.

```
AccountID   Invoice Date    TotalSavings
ABC 6/30/2012   10
ABC 12/31/2013  20
ABC 6/1/2014    30
BCA 9/30/2011   40
BCA 1/31/2012   50
BCA 11/30/2011  60
CBA 3/1/2015    70
CBA 3/1/2015    80
```

I'm looking for an output like this

```
AccountID   Invoice Date    TotalSavings
ABC 6/30/2012   10
BCA 9/30/2011   40
CBA 3/1/2015    150
```

I would appreciate any help that can be offered on this forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `joins` with `subquery`

```
select a.accountid, s.invoicedate, 
       sum(s.TotalSavings) as TotalSavings
from tblAccount a 
left join tblInvoice s on s.accountid = a.accountid 
where s.invoicedate is not null and s.TotalSavings > 0 and
      s.invoicedate = (select min(invoicedate) 
                       from tblInvoice 
                       where accountid = a.accountid)
group by a.accountid, s.invoicedate;
```

You could also switch your `joins` with only `exists`

```
select accountid, invoicedate, sum(TotalSavings) as TotalSavings
from tblInvoice s 
where exists (select 1 from tblAccount where accountid  = s.accountid) and 
TotalSavings > 0 and
invoicedate = (select min(invoicedate) from tblInvoice where accountid  = s.accountid)
group by accountid, invoicedate
```

Comment: Thank you very much All.. Yogesh's solution worked without any issues...!!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested the below code by imitating tables like yours but it should be good to go:

```
; WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT TA.AccountID, MIN(TI.InvoiceDate) AS InvoiceDate
    FROM tblAccount AS TA
        LEFT JOIN tblInvoice AS TI ON TA.AccountID = TI.AccountID -- could be INNER JOIN because you're filtering out the NULL rows on the right with TI.InvoiceDate IS NOT NULL in the WHERE clause
    WHERE TI.TotalSavings > 0 AND TI.InvoiceDate IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT c.AccountID, c.InvoiceDate, SUM(i.TotalSavings) AS TotalSavings
FROM CTE c
    INNER JOIN tblInvoice i ON c.AccountID = i.AccountID AND c.InvoiceDate = i.InvoiceDate
GROUP BY c.AccountID, c.InvoiceDate;
```

Pretty much, you first have to find the minimum invoice date that had some savings for a certain account (`TotalSavings > 0`) and then you have to sum up all the savings on that day for that account.

Answer (score 1):

By my understanding, i do this and you can use following CTE method.

```
   with
    rownumber(id, dateColumn, amt, rn)
   as(
    select i.id, dateColumn, sum(amt), ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by i.id 
    ORDER BY dateColumn) rn from tblinvoice i join 
    tblAccount a on a.id = i.id
    group by i.id, dateColumn
   )select id, dateColumn, amt from rownumber where rn = 1


--tlbaccount
id
1
2
3

--tlbInvoice  --same id with same date. And same id with diff date.
id  dateColumn  amt
1   2018-04-14  10
1   2018-04-14  20
2   2018-04-14  20
2   2018-03-14  20

--actual O/P --sum amts of same ids with same date and min date from same id with diff date
id  dateColumn  amt
1   2018-04-14  30
2   2018-03-14  20
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the null or left.
The s in the where kills the left join.
Why do you even need account?

```
select s.accountid, s.invoicedate, 
       sum(s.TotalSavings) as TotalSavings
from tblInvoice s 
where s.TotalSavings > 0 
  and s.invoicedate = ( select min(invoicedate) 
                        from tblInvoice 
                        where accountid = s.accountid )
group by s.accountid
order by s.accountid;
```